# with rosserial, changes to arduino library .h files have no effect

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I successfully setup and am using rosserial, but want to make some changes to the .h files located in the arduino library, for example

...sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h

or

...sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros/nodehandle.h

but for some reason, changes to those files do not get incorporated into the build made with the arduino IDE.  I have tried closing the IDE, rebooting, etc.  It seems as if the library files are coming from some other location.

I have a lot of experience with arduino and custom libraries and this one has me completely baffled.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73639/with-rosserial,-changes-to-arduino-library-.h-files-have-no-effect/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2013-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on ferg's answer to a related question, in the arduino IDE I went to File, Preferences and selected verbose build.  With that I discovered that the IDE was using an old, backup copy of ros_lib.  I thought it would not do that since I had renamed the folder ros_lib_old, but forgot that odd things happen in arduino libraries that have more than one file with the same name, even if they are in different directories.

So just moving the backup copy from the libraries folder fixed the problem.

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2013-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0